# Display properties of selected item in a TreeViewer

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, eclipse-emf

I am a beginner in the use of Eclipse RCP and EMF.
To improve the interface of an RCP application I would like to display the tree structure of my data and when an item is selected that the properties view is updated.

I manage to display my tree with a TreeViewer and I manage to add a listener with `myTree.addTreeSelectionListener()`. My data already exists and has been modelled with EMF. How can I display the attributes of the selected items in the properties view? Do you have any ideas? I haven't found a clear answer on the internet.

Comment: were u able to bind the data to the tree?

Comment: I can display my data in my tree viewer so I think it's bind

Comment: There is an example [here](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Properties-View/properties-view.html)